# How do handle if-else cases in angular ng-show without ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have several div attributes and only one of them will be shown at a time. I now have sth like this:

```
div(ng-show='x & y & z')
 ...

div(ng-show='(g || y) & z')
 ...

div(ng-show='k || z')
 ...
```

Since ng-switch needs an "on" attribute and i have to call here many different functions to evaluate my ng-shows, i dont know what a better approach would be. But this is definitely not delivering the best performace. Because **as soon as the first ng-show is evaluated to TRUE, i dont want to evaluate others**.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif looks relevant.  Without using this, I am not aware of a straightforward way of doing what you want apart from writing a custom directive (which is what this library does).

Comment: i have also seen that library but i am not really sure how it internally works. I just want to be able not to evaluate unneeded conditions.

Comment: i wrote a question in that library's github: https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif/issues/14

Comment: You could create a directive, and pass in the relevant properties and create a function in the directive that does the checking and supplies the HTML via a template.

Comment: could you post an example? I was not really using a directive until now..

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what the object looks like or what you're trying to bulid, I will just give an example of building the directive...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.letters = { 
      x: true,
      y: true,
      z: true,
      g: false,
      k: false
    };
});

myApp.directive('checkLetters', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { letters: '=' },
        template: '<div>X is {{letters.x}}, but K is {{letters.k}}</div>'
    };
});
```

Your HTML will then simply have the directive in the page like this...

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <check-letters letters="letters"></check-letters>
</body>
```

You can build your own template inline, or even create a HTML page for the template and build that to your needs.

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jqV702q0nOVWgvkrq7O9?p=preview) for you to check out.

Comment: but as i see from your example, your letters object will be prepared / all conditions will be evaluated (true, false, or a function if you had any) as soon as controller is called. or am i missing sth?

Comment: You haven't explained how the letters are populated? maybe make the question clearer?

Comment: I wrote "i have to call here many different functions to evaluate my ng-shows". So they are functions. And i made it clear with bold letters: as soon as the first ng-show is evaluated to TRUE, i dont want to evaluate others